# How to load more than 2GB of assets into a Unity3D Resource File

Tags: resources, limit, unity-game-engine

I am trying to load more than 2GB of assets into my Resource File. (Yes, I have alot of assets in the scene!)

But, there is a 2GB limit, and when I go over that limit, my whole scene disappears in Play mode. (It's fine in Editor mode.)

How can this be overcome? Can multiple Resource Files be used somehow?

I'm running 32-bit.

Thanks!
Adam

Answer (score 0):

Remembering back to 32bit windows, 2gb was the max supported ram.  I don't think you would have this issue with the 64bit version. Just a guess based on experience. I wouldn't have even answered if I didn't see you specifically state you are running 32bit.